# Installing mc (midnight commander) without root access?

Tags: install, permission, user-account, terminal

How do I do that? The normal installers (with `.pkg` files) ask for an admin password. It is possible to run normal mac software without admin access, but how do I run and install this shell software?

Comment: Why can’t you add yourself to the sudoers file?

Comment: The salient point is really that if you don't have admin rights, then there are limits to what you can do. "Contact your System Administrator."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile it yourself or use [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/), that doesn't require root access.

Comment: I can't install homebrew without root: user@mac is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir /usr/local

Comment: And compiling it myself also requires a lot of sudo - which I can't do. Hell, there is no gcc and cc on this mac.

Comment: Without gcc you will be unable to install it, with or without homebrew. Btw homebrew can be installed anywhere, see the [official documentation](http://wiki.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/installation).

Comment: "NOTE: This method might not work for machines managed with Directory Services." - which is exactly the case for my machine.

Comment: If you get an error regarding the SSL cert for the mc download be sure to upgrade homebrew first, as there is a fix in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it elsewhere on a Mac where you do have the necessary tools installed. Move the binary over to the other machine.